# Is Update 3 of Visual Studio 2015 cumulative?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Can I install Visual Studio Community Edition RTM and then Update 3?
Or, do I need to Install Update 1 then 2 then 3?

Comment: Why not install Update 3 [directly](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs)? I don't even think there is an obvious way to install RTM without the updates.

Comment: Update 3 is only an update, and I thought the linked page was the base (RTM). But I'll try it and see if it's really update 3). So, if you post that as an answer, and I verify it I"ll mark it as Answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [VS install I downloaded](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs) (latest one) *includes* SP3.

So it appears that the current download of VS includes the latest SP updates.

Comment: Thanks to @Rakete1111  for the info.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is cumulative. Moreover, each time a new update is released, Microsoft immediately makes sure there is no access to any previous updates. All links to previous updates get redirected to the latest update. (More precisely, all links simply lead to the online installer, which always downloads the latest update).

This is a major PITA, BTW, since there's no immediate solution to new code-breaking bugs that Microsoft often introduces into new updates. Update 3 is quite problematic in that regard.

For this reason, if you already have Visual Studio installed, it is highly recommended to make a snapshot of your system before installing any further VS updates. That way you will always be able to revert to the previous version in case the new update is broken.